# Play audio when hidden input change value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to play an audio file when the hidden input field changes value. 
This hidden input is in the `<table>` which is refreshed by Ajax to update the values.

What I need to do is, (for example) when the value turns to Yes the `Clap.wav` needs to play, otherwise, when the value turns to No`boo.wav` must play.

Anyone can give me a sample code for this or an idea? 
Thank you for those who are willing to help.

Here are some of my codes

This is the hidden input field code. It is located on table with the id of `connExcel` on  platinum.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="indVal" id="indVal" value=" <?php echo $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, 5)->getOldCalculatedValue();  ?> ">
```

And here are some of my Ajax codes

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
    document.getElementById('connExcel').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('AutoRefresh()',100); // JavaScript function calls AutoRefresh() every 3 seconds
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("GET","<?php if( isset( $isAdmin ) &&  $isAdmin == TRUE ){ echo  '../../library/tosloader.php?page='. $pageID; } else {  echo  ../library/tosloader.php?page='. $pageID; }  ?>",true);
```

the 'tosloader.php' just including the platinum.php to refresh the table.

Comment: just a suggestion ,  why don't you in the code that sets the hidden value - play the wav from there?

Comment: because I need to determine if the value change. I have tried to use the .change of JQuery but it wont work.

Comment: And how does the value of the *hidden* input change?

Comment: That means that you want to check in an time-interval for that input has changed his value?? Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: @PeeHaa It change by the Ajax. The table, where hidden input field located,  is refreshing automatically by Ajax.

Comment: Uhhhmm the ajax doesn't do anything without your code telling to do it :) So why can't you just do whatever it is you want to do in the success callback of the ajax request?

Comment: You can see the code on the top.

Comment: Take a look at my demo and put `checkInputValue();` inside your `AutoRefresh()` function.

Answer (score 0):

in the code where you set the hidden input's value do this

```
$('#myHiddenID').val(myValue).trigger('change');
```

then just use the change event like this

```
$('#myHiddenID').change(function(){
     var OnOff = $(this).val();
     if (OnOff == "ON") { // play clap}
     if (OnOff == "OFF) { //play boo}
})
```

Comment: I don't know where put the first code. Since PHP codes is the source of the value of hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eqigiy/2/edit)***

HTML:

```
<input id="inp" type="text" value="NO" />
```

JS:

```
function checkInputValue(){

    var files = { "YES": "Clap.wav", "NO": "boo.wav" };
    var sound = new Audio( files[ $('#inp').val() ] );
    sound.play();

}

checkInputValue(); // USE WHEREVER YOU LIKE
```

**Or you can do like:**

name your files: `yes.wav` and `no.wav`

```
function checkInputValue( snd ){
    var sound = new Audio( snd+'.wav');
    sound.play();     
}

var AJAXval = ("YES").toLowerCase() ; // the returned value to lowercase
checkInputValue( AJAXval );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're completely adding and removing the element from the DOM, so you'll need to watch the `DOMNodeInserted` event. Luckily we can bind to it. We'll assume the hidden input has a class of `hiddenInput`. Then we'll need to grab our source elements, aptly named `<source id="yesAudio"..../>` and `<source id="noAudio".../>` we'll use jquery's `.get()` method and then use the HTML5 audio api's `.play();` to invoke them.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
    if(e.srcElement.className == 'hiddenInput'){
        if(e.srcElement.value == 'yes'){
            $('#yesAudio').get().play();    
        }else{
            $('#noAudio').get().play();
        }
    }        
});​​​​​
```

I think this is what you want.